# Auto-populating 'from' and 'to' columns of a line feature according to the point features the line begins and ends at

Tags: qgis, sql, autofields

Within QGIS, I have a 'cable' layer and within such layer I have the columns 'from' and 'to'. The use of this 'cable' layer demonstrates a real-life cable travelling from one piece of equipment to another.

Say I had a layer called 'equipment' with two point features I want a cable to connect to. These two points are labelled 'Point A' and 'Point B', is there a way to auto-populate two columns in the 'cable' layer to show that the line drawn is starting from 'Point A' and ending at 'Point B'?

I do not use PostgreSQL, this project is a private creation.

Comment: There isn't any correlation at all between private/non-private project creation and PostgreSQL use. If anything, it's the reverse (since non-free databases are unlikely to be used for personal projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new field for start- and end point with Field calculator and this expression and replace `point` with the name of the point layerm `name` with the name of the attribute field containing the point's name and change `start_point` to `end_point` when creating the end point's name:

```
array_max(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_nearest ('point',$id,limit:=2),  -- change point to your layer name
        case 
        when intersects (
            start_point($geometry),  -- change to end_point for attribute of end point
            geometry (get_feature_by_id('point',@element))   -- change point to your layer name
        ) 
        then attribute (get_feature_by_id ('point',@element),'name')   -- change point and name to your layer/field names
        end
))
```

[image]